# Convert to number in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables Stock 1 and Stock 2 in Stock 1 there is an ID_1 (nvarchar(Max) data type) column and in Stock 2 there is ID_2 (Decimal data type) column.

Wherever ID_1 matched with ID_2 it should give Product Matching ID in result column

Stock 1

| ID_1 |
| --- |
| 23495_1 |
| 32212_1 |
| 778271_2 |
| 66410 |
| 66411 |
| 662527_2 |

Stock 2

| Product Matching ID | ID_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 892828_1 | NULL |
| 1000293_3 | 66410 |
| 98271_5 | 66411 |
| 990112_2 | 55421 |
| 77885_232 | 099281 |

In the above table 66410 and 66411 are common so I am looking for the Product matching ID from Stock 2 table

I am getting error:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

I am doing left join when ID_1 = ID_2 then Product Matching ID else ID_1

Query I am using

```
select
    case when s1.ID_1 = s2.ID_2 then s2.Product Matching ID
    else s1.ID_1 end as [Product ID]
from Stock_1 s1
left join Stock_2 s2 on s2.ID_2 = s1.ID_1
```

I want all the data from Stock 1 table and wherever it has no record should be null.

Comment: Could you share your query?

Comment: select

Case when s1.ID_1 = s2.ID_2 then s2.Product Matching ID
else s1.ID_1 end as [Product ID]
from Stock_1 s1

left Join Stock_2 s2 on s2.ID_2 = s1.ID_1

Comment: [edit] it into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Does it work for you using TRY_CAST?

```
select isnull(s2.[Product Matching ID], s1.ID_1) [Product ID] 
from Stock_1 s1 
left Join Stock_2 s2 on s2.ID_2= try_cast(s1.ID_1 as int)
```

Comment: @Sandy some of your string ids cannot be converted to a numeric value, hence your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the string data to integer as :

```
select t2.product_matching_id
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
on t1.id_1 = (cast(isnull(t2.id_2,0)) as int)
```

The update you need to make in your query would be:

```
Case 
    when s1.ID_1 = (cast(isnull(s2.ID_2,0)) as int) 
        then s2.Product_Matching_ID 
    else s1.ID_1 end 
    as [Product ID] from Stock_1 s1

left Join Stock_2 s2 on (cast(isnull(s2.ID_2,0)) as int) = s1.ID_1
```

Comment: I dont want innner join I want all the data from Stock 1 table

Comment: @Sandy i have updated based on the query in your question